# facebook iframe cross domain cookies issue on safari

Tags: php, facebook, cookies, safari, facebook-apps

ı have facebook application works on ff,ie,chrome.

but ı have problem on safari.

ı have links one page to another. but when ı click its redirecting to index.php.

ı read some articles and tried to many ways but stil ı couldt figure it out.

**ı read this:**

[Facebook Iframe App with multiple pages in Safari Session Variables not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691864/facebook-iframe-app-with-multiple-pages-in-safari-session-variables-not-persisti)

and

[Setting cross-domain cookies in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari)

Answer (score 2):

Safari blocks 3rd party cookies by default. See: http://webpolicy.org/2012/02/17/safari-trackers/

Answer (score 2):

We solved this by opening a popup on a login button.  The popup opens a url on the new domain and then quickly closes the popup. This means that tbe user have now visited the domain (in the top url) and allows us to save cookies on that domain. This works good in a facebook app since we can not use other solutions such as posting from the parent frame to the iframe.

Comment: Could you explain more? You just only open the popup or send cookie to save as well?

Comment: You need to open the domain in a popup. After the popup has closed you are allowed to do crossdomain cookies :)