# IFrame not working in Safari

Tags: html, iframe, web, safari, mobile-safari

I have an `iframe` in my web page. It works fine in FF and Chrome but not in Safari (I'm using Safari 6.0)

This is my code:

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Pengower</title>     
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div id="container">  
            <iframe name="news" id="news"   
                src="http://www.penapplications.net/ImogenApps/?Pengower:CRM:Pengower_News">  
            </iframe>  
       </div><!--end container div-->  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Funny thing is that, if I access the `src` url and then access the `iframe` page, then the `iframe` shows the content properly, but if I just access the `iframe` page without accessing the `src` url page before, it does not show the content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `iframe` seems to be redirecting to a [mediating page (`penDummyLogon.aspx)`](https://www.penapplications.net/ImogenApps/penDummyLogon.aspx?qkfjllH) which attempts to automatically submit a form to the [final page (`main.aspx`)](https://www.penapplications.net/ImogenApps/main.aspx) and set a cookie.

Since this method of setting a cookie seems to have been blocked in the recent Safari versions, the user arrives at the final page without the cookie. `main.aspx` doesn't seem to be able to handle the missing cookie, and as a result its expected content doesn't load.

For more about this subject see [Does the technique for setting third-party cookies in iframes in Safari still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060820/does-the-technique-for-setting-third-party-cookies-in-iframes-in-safari-still-wo) and [Safari 3rd party cookie iframe trick no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working/)

Comment: Google Chrome's Developer Tools (`Ctrl+Shift+J`) provides a handy log of http requests generated by the page, under the "Network" tab. Also, you can see the form in the page's source code (`Ctrl+U`). As for cookies, they can usually be seen in the browser's privacy settings. For example, in Google Chrome cookies can be found this settings page: chrome://chrome/settings/cookies

Answer (score 0):

the third party cookies are not working in safari.but in asp.net you can achieve this by using the cookieless sessions.

for more information refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx