# Function doesn't work in safari on windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

While this syntax works on all other browser, safari on windows throws an error

```
$("#kibana").contents().find('.navbar-nav')[0].remove();
```

The error is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

The element does exist. I checked using the debugger.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "kibana" is id of iframe in which I am downloading third party content. and before executing this $("#kibana").contents().find('.navbar-nav')[0].remove() when I am checking in debugger, $("#kibana").contents().find('.navbar-nav') shows me array with 2 <ul>. So I am trying to remove the first one via this code.

Comment: Looks like somebody did experience an issue with `iframe` on Safari as well, but not directly relavant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105611/iframe-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `[]` on a jQuery object, you are retrieving the underlying DOM node. [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) isn't fully cross-browser compatible on native DOM elements.

Instead, you can use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to retrieve the element while still having it wrapped in jQuery. That way you can use the cross-browser comptabile [`.remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method:

```
$("#kibana").contents().find('.navbar-nav').eq(0).remove();
```