# iframe is not loading content from another domain in Safari?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, safari

I have an iframe which suppose to show the content from another domain on the basis of given ID which is provided as a get parameter.

`<iframe src="https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.com.xx/Home/Customer?Code=<?php print_r($_SESSION['xxxx']); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen height="780" style="width: 124%;"></iframe>`

This is working properly on Chrome but in Safari it is showing the not logged in state. (page when id is not provided).
It may be third party cookie issue. I don't know how to overcome it.

Please Help!

Comment: could be duplicate of 
[IFrame not working in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105611/iframe-not-working-in-safari)