# Opening external application in iframe not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.location

I have a site embedded in an iframe from where I want to launch a mobile app. The following is bound to an onClick action on my button, and works in both Chrome and Firefox on my Android:

```
window.location = "scheme://app.com/?action=xxxxx"
```

However, when trying on Safari on iOS, nothing happens at all when clicking the button. If i go to the site directly (instead of iframing it) it works perfectly.

The same thing happens if I use an anchor tag:

```
<a href="scheme://app.com?action=xxxxx"></a>
```

I tried to fix this by using `window.top.location`, but then I run into Same-origin policy issues. The site that is hosting the iframe is on a different domain which I can't control.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105875/3904529

Comment: That's not the same issue at all, the iframe loads just fine.

Comment: Did you checked the browser's console to see what's wrong?