# Facebook canvas app and Safari 5 - trick with post to iframe does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

I have a problem with my facebook app and Safari 5 (only Safari 5). Previously it was enough to have an iframe and do a post to it to get cross domain cookies working. Now it does not seem to work anymore with Safari 5

```
<body background="background.jpg" onload="document.forms['qmainapp'].submit();">
<form name="qmainapp" id="qmainapp" target="mainapp" method="POST" action="webappmainframe.php">
<input type="Text" name="aText" value="ddd">
</form>
<iframe name="mainapp" id="mainapp" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="480" height="800" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:144;" >...Wait</iframe>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is this form submittion into an iframe is for?

Comment: Trying to get around OAuthException with Safari 5. For Safari 4 it was enough to make any POST to your canvas app to get it working, but it does not seem to work with Safari 5. Original solution was posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691864/facebook-iframe-app-with-multiple-pages-in-safari-session-variables-not-persisti but it does not work anymore