# Facebook Apps Error Getting Session or Cookie in Mac Safari Browser?

Tags: php, cross-domain, facebook-apps, safari

I already did a research on facebook as well in here, the solution I landed is on this page

[Facebook Iframe App with multiple pages in Safari Session Variables not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691864/facebook-iframe-app-with-multiple-pages-in-safari-session-variables-not-persisti)

also I already did include this code but still not working

```
<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

but its still not working, is Facebook implemented a new technique for cross-domain cookies/sessions for iframe in Safari?

I hope you can help me due to I'm already search any solution for 2 days and I cant successfully fix this issue.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That header fix my problem on IE but not on safari:

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') ) header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```