# Session in Laravel does not work inside the Facebook Application Iframe

Tags: facebook, session, session-cookies, laravel, facebook-iframe

I have a facebook app that runs inside an iframe. After the user allow permissions from the app I'm expecting facebook to send me $_REQUEST variables that I use to retrieve user data and it is working well. The problem is after I put the users data in Laravel Session using        `Session::put()` and then `Session::save()`, on the next request the session is gone. So my app cannot retrieve the Session anymore. I really don't know why during the test all of my browsers work, `(Safari, Firefox, Chrome)`. So I put some error checking to email me everytime there is an Session Error and still I got 30+ emails per day telling that `Chrome` has no Session, and some users were posting about the App returning Error. I'm really struggling for this problem for days now. I've implemented some fix adding `P3P headers` and adding `favicon` on my site, still no avail.

Here is my code:

```
Route::filter('before', function() 
{
    // Do stuff before every request to your application...
    header('P3P:CP="NOI DEV PSAi COM NAV OTR STP DEM HONK IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi CAO PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

//safari 3rd party fix cookie fix
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    if (! count($_COOKIE) > 0 && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari')) {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') == false) {
            session_start();
            $page_url = Config::get('custom.fb_page');
            if (isset($_GET["start_session"]))
                die(header("Location:" . $page_url));
            $sid = session_id();
            if (!isset($_GET["sid"]))
            {
                if(isset($_POST["signed_request"]))
                    $_SESSION["signed_request"] = $_POST["signed_request"];
                die(header("Location:?sid=" . $sid));
            }
            if (empty($sid) || $_GET["sid"] != $sid)
                die('<script>top.window.location="?start_session=true";</script>');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//and the code that sets Laravel Session

```
Route::any('tab/(:any?)', function ($res = null)
{
    //$response = some_function_to_get_token($_REQUEST['signed_request']);
    if($response && isset($response['oauth_token']))
    {
        Session::put('my_session_for_token', $response['oauth_token']);
        Session::save();

        $redirect = Redirect::to('my_awesome_page');
    }
    else
        $redirect = Redirect::to('permission');
}
```

**EDIT**

I've already tried setting $_SESSION and commenting out Session::put() but it doesn't set my $_SESSION at all. Next thing I tried was uploading a sessionchecker.php script and tried it using the browser.

heres the code for session check:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['views']))
       $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'] + 1;
    else
       $_SESSION['views'] = 0;

   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump(session_id()); // I should stay the same
   var_dump($_SESSION); // I should start at 0 and increase
   echo '</pre>';
```

and it working as expected, Im suspecting that it has something to do with Redirect::to().
P.S. I've already tried configuring Laravel to use Cookie and File but still the error occurs.

Comment: Perhaps try with the native PHP session - and see if that works - to help isolate the issue?

Comment: p.s. what session storage are you using? cookie, database, redis etc?

Comment: i've tried setting it using PHP default $_SESSION but it does not work. Ill update my question on what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel problem. This is a classic Safari/Internet explorer 3rd party cookie problem.

Try googling for "safari cookie fix" or check out some of these questions here, for example:
[Facebook Iframe App with multiple pages in Safari Session Variables not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691864/facebook-iframe-app-with-multiple-pages-in-safari-session-variables-not-persisti)