# Facebook form app inside iframe loses cookies for Safari browsers in Windows platform

Tags: facebook, iframe, cookies, safari

I have a facebook app built using iframe. It works ok on most modern browsers except Safari on Windows platform. On Safari windows platform, the cookies seem to get lost as a user move from  initial form page to 2nd page with questions.

Here is the live link

http://on.fb.me/1hCfgOX

Can someone help me on how to fix this?

Comment: I realize that The problem is that the default behavior of Safari is to only accept cookies from sites that you visit. This excludes "third party" cookies. Safari treats the page inside an IFRAME as a third-party site, it will refuse those cookies. What is the solution with this other than using P3P?

Comment: _“What is the solution with this other than using P3P?”_ – not using cookies …?

Comment: I am using cookies. However, only in Safari (windows) cookies get lost as I move from page to page.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any one please give a fix and i will give a bouty to that answer. I am using this code header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"'); on top of my pages. Thanks

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146173/session-null-in-iframe-in-asp-net-mvc-only-in-safari-browser/20221881#comment36525857_20197770

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a fix for it which works perfectly. Checkout the following links:

[Safari 3rd party cookie iframe trick no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working)

[Facebook Iframe App with multiple pages in Safari Session Variables not persisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691864/facebook-iframe-app-with-multiple-pages-in-safari-session-variables-not-persisti)

And

http://lightyearsoftware.com/2009/11/on-the-pain-of-developing-for-facebook/

I hope this will fix your issue also, as it fixed mine. If you got any problem, let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

besides header, you might also need to add `w3c/p3p.xml` and `w3c/policy.p3p` files to your website. See here for more details and sample files: [Session null in IFrame in ASP.net MVC only in safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146173/session-null-in-iframe-in-asp-net-mvc-only-in-safari-browser/20221881#20221881)

Comment: it does not depend on the server type - it's just a couple of static files for the browser to retrieve - so yes - try that please.