# Session null in IFrame in ASP.net MVC only in safari browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Page contains IFrame and session is null only in case of Safari. My Safari version is 5.1.7

I am using MVC 4.5 Everything works in other browsers perfectly. I am using the below code..

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
     base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
     GetFirstError();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

we had **exactly** the same issue - FB app did not work in Safari in ASP.Net MVC project. Here is what we did to fix it:

1. Add P3P header to all reposonses. You can configure it at IIS server level: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324013 - or do it directly in global.asax:

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("P3P", "CP=\"NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT\"");
   }
   ```
2. Create `w3c` folder in the root of your website (so-called well-known location) and upload `p3p.xml` and `policy.p3p` files into it as per this Microsoft guide: [How to Deploy P3P Privacy Policies on Your Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537341%28VS.85%29.aspx)

here is my p3p.xml file:

```
<META>
  <POLICY-REFERENCES>
    <POLICY-REF about="/w3c/policy.p3p">
      <INCLUDE>/</INCLUDE>
      <COOKIE-INCLUDE/>
    </POLICY-REF>
  </POLICY-REFERENCES>
</META>
```

and policy.p3p (sorry it's long but i'm not sure how to hide it as a spoiler):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<POLICIES xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/01/P3Pv1">
    <!-- Generated by IBM P3P Policy Editor version Beta 1.12 built 2/27/04 1:19 PM -->

    <!-- Expiry information for this policy -->
    <EXPIRY max-age="86400"/>

<POLICY
    xml:lang="uk">
    <!-- Description of the entity making this policy statement. -->
    <ENTITY>
    <DATA-GROUP>
    </DATA-GROUP>
    </ENTITY>

    <!-- Disclosure -->
    <ACCESS><nonident/></ACCESS>

    <!-- No dispute information -->

    <!-- Statement for group "Basic information" -->
    <STATEMENT>
        <EXTENSION optional="yes">
            <GROUP-INFO xmlns="http://www.software.ibm.com/P3P/editor/extension-1.0.html" name="Basic information"/>
        </EXTENSION>

    <!-- Consequence -->
    <CONSEQUENCE>
Data collected from all Web users: access logs, and search strings (if entered).</CONSEQUENCE>

    <!-- Use (purpose) -->
    <PURPOSE><admin/><current/><develop/></PURPOSE>

    <!-- Recipients -->
    <RECIPIENT><ours/></RECIPIENT>

    <!-- Retention -->
    <RETENTION><indefinitely/></RETENTION>

    <!-- Base dataschema elements. -->
    <DATA-GROUP>
    <DATA ref="#dynamic.clickstream"/>
    <DATA ref="#dynamic.http"/>
    <DATA ref="#dynamic.searchtext"/>
    </DATA-GROUP>
</STATEMENT>

    <!-- Statement for group "Cookies" -->
    <STATEMENT>
        <EXTENSION optional="yes">
            <GROUP-INFO xmlns="http://www.software.ibm.com/P3P/editor/extension-1.0.html" name="Cookies"/>
        </EXTENSION>

    <!-- Consequence -->
    <CONSEQUENCE>
Cookies are used to track visitors to our site, 
so we can better understand what portions of our site best serve you.</CONSEQUENCE>

    <!-- Use (purpose) -->
    <PURPOSE><develop/><tailoring/></PURPOSE>

    <!-- Recipients -->
    <RECIPIENT><ours/></RECIPIENT>

    <!-- Retention -->
    <RETENTION><business-practices/></RETENTION>

    <!-- Base dataschema elements. -->
    <DATA-GROUP>
    <DATA ref="#dynamic.cookies" optional="yes"><CATEGORIES><uniqueid/></CATEGORIES></DATA>
    </DATA-GROUP>
</STATEMENT>

<!-- End of policy -->
</POLICY>
</POLICIES>
```

Comment: Anyone know if this still works? Or have Apple patched this one too?

Comment: Added this to one of our facebook apps and it doesn't seem to work (with Safari). :(

Comment: @Jag Did you ever find a solution that worked for you?  I also tried the solution described here and am still seeing problems in Safari in my Facebook app.  Any answers that you may have found would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Safari is set do NOT accept 3rd party cookies by default. This means when you're visiting domain A and it embeds domain B in an iframe, then it won't accept cookies from B until the user interacts with the content of the iframe.

This scenario bit me badly while developing a facebook application that needed sessions and the client didn't accept the solution of telling the user to enable 3rd party cookies. This is the workaround that I implemented and is working ever since:

- check if the User-Agent header contains the string Safari
- check if we get no cookies at all
- if both of the above is true, issue a javascript redirect to my domain, to a special cookiefix page (meaning the following outut: `<script>top.location = "http://example.com/cookiefix";</script>`) - the JS is needed to bust out of the iframe
- on that page do nothing but set a dummy session variable
- redirect to the original page and enjoy my session cookie, which is technically a 3rd party cookie but it was accepted already and doesn't need to cange

Comment: This actually works very well with Facebook apps. You already have a redirection to your app after requesting the permissions. You just need to establish a session there (so that the cookie is set), and everything will just work (TM).

Comment: @apfelbox for my usecase I needed session before the app auth, so I needed my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use request tracing and look at the incoming request cookie or use a debugging proxy to look at the values on the client (or browser debug tools). Are cookies turned off? Is your session guid changing every time coming from server to client - in which case the session isn't remaining established

Comment: i did not downvote - but I agree with the one who did - how does your answer help (or even answers) the question? He already knows cookies are not working..

Comment: @avs099 the issue is the session is null. One of the first diagnostic things to check is if the session id is being kept. Session can still be null from code issue.Cookies weren't actually mentioned at all in the OP. Since the default session provider will regenerate ids, this lets you know if values are clearing, being kept, etc. Its a little known thing to look for. I've written session provider code before, so using some knowledge here on that to try to get more diagnostic info. This helps determine if the cookie is even coming to the client or back to server, essential first tracing step.

Answer (score -2):

One way is to DisAllow cookies to never block it. in following way.

> Go to Preferences.
>  Select Privacy 
> Never Block Cookies