# CakePHP session lost in Safari and IE between pages on Facebook

Tags: facebook, session, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk, cakephp-2.5

I'm developing a Facebook app on CakePHP framework and I'm trying to do one simple thing:

```
// get user
$user = $this->Facebook->api('/me');

// store the user id into session
$this->Session->write('User.id', $user['id']);
```

But as soon as I change page the session is lost in Safari and I cannot get the id from the session no matter what.

I have found numerous solutions here and on other forums tried them all, but I haven't managed to solve this problem. Nothing works for me or I have been doing it wrong... Anyone managed to found a working solution for this?

Any help would be really appreciated, thnx.

Comment: I have a session (if I echo it on the landing page it is set), but if user clicks on another page inside the app that session is lost.

Comment: OK, that is the problem I would like to solve... Why do I lose the session in Safari? And how would I not lose it!?

Comment: Session id keeps on changing on every refresh in safari.

Comment: I have checked the log, no errors related to the application in there.

Comment: If I run the app outside the facebook iframe everything works OK. The session id stays the same on every reload... but inside the facebook iframe id keeps on changing and only in Safari, in Firefox it works and the session id stays the same through the app...

Comment: That's the kind of info that's very useful - please *put it in the question*. I don't remember the solution but e.g. [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927249/facebook-form-app-inside-iframe-loses-cookies-for-safari-browsers-in-windows-pla). The last time I looked at that problem - the solution was to avoid all the cheating and prompt the user to accept 3rd party cookies.

Comment: One interesting thing I discovered: If I open the app directly through the url so it may set the session then everything works OK even if I go back to facebook... I'm thinking about doing a redirect outside facebook, just to start the session, saving session id along the way and then check if id the same, avoiding another redirect inside the fb app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. The problem is Safari cookie policy, user has to change to allow all cookies in their Safari settings.

But I have figured out that if I first reload the page outside the facebook iframe and set the session there, the session remains the same even inside the facebook iframe.

So I created another controller action just to start a new session and store its id inside the session for later use:

```
public function safari_session_hack()
{
    $app_url = "app_url"; // the full url of your app on facebook
    session_start();
    $this->Session->write('Session.id', session_id());
    die(header("Location:" . $app_url)); // redirect back to the FB app
}
```

Then on my FB app landing page I have this code:

```
// Session fix for Safari
if (!$this->Session->read('Session.id') && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari')) {
    echo '<script>top.location.href="' . Router::fullbaseUrl() . Router::url(array('controller' => 'main', 'action' => 'safari_session_hack')) . '"</script>';
    die;
}
```

All it does is it checks if the session id is not set and if the browser is Safari. Then it redirects to the safari_session_hack() action, starts the session on the outside page, saves its id inside the session and redirects back to the page.

Now everything works fine and the session is not being lost or destroyed between pages, so you can do user login and other stuff that requires session data inside your FB app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper code which you can download from github

```
//Example AppController setup
public $components = array('Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        ),
        'authorize' => 'Controller'
    ),
    'Facebook.Connect' => array('model' => 'User')
);
```

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

Comment: I tried all that, even did my own custom FB login function... Even by using Auth and logging in the user that session gets lost too when user goes to another page in the app. This is limited only to the mentioned browsers, in Firefox and Chrome it works like a charm...

Comment: I get the user Id from FB SDK, the session just gets lost between pages in Safari...