# Fosuserbundle safari csrf token

Tags: symfony, safari, csrf, fosuserbundle

i have a probleme when i want to register on my website with safari because symfony2 told me that the csrf token is invalide ( but it's working on firefox and chrome !). i have only change register_content.html.twig and the layout of the bundle

```
#register_content.html.twig

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<div class="content_registration">
        <div class="content_registration_why">
            <h2>Rejoignez nous !</li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/nemiuser/images/pin.svg') }}" />
                    <p>Faites une offre sur vos créations préférées !</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/nemiuser/images/pin.svg') }}" />
                    <p>Revendez vos précédents achats !</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/nemiuser/images/pin.svg') }}" />
                    <p> Proposez vos plus belles oeuvres !</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content_registration_form_content">
            <div class="content_registration_form_content_form">
                <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
                    <table>
                        <tr clospan=2 >
                            <td>{{ form_label(form.email) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_errors(form.email) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form_label(form.username) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form.username) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" id="register_button" class="myButton" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#layout.html.twig (layout of the bundle)

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% block header %}
        {% include ':header:header.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock header %}
        {% block content %}
            {{ parent() }}
            <div class="content">
                {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% block fos_user_content %}
                {% endblock fos_user_content %}
            </div>
        {% block js_elem %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/user.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock js_elem %}
    {% endblock content %}
    {% block footer %}
        {% include ':footer:footer.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock footer %}
{% endblock body %}
```

any idea why ?

I have already check a lot of stuff on google but i am still stuck (and mad because it's working on the other browser).

thxxxxx

Edit : It's working now on LOCALHOST but not on my server :/ i remove completely all facebooks'  features but it's still not working

Comment: Is your app running inside of an iframe?

Comment: i have a facebook button to like and share "div.fb-like.likefb.fb_iframe_widget" does it count ? else i have nothing more

Comment: I had issues with the session cookie for Safari.  This is just a wild guess but maybe this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927249/facebook-form-app-inside-iframe-loses-cookies-for-safari-browsers-in-windows-pla

Comment: hello, i am sur i am using no iframe now and it's working on local so maybe the probleme is from the php version on my serveur but it have the last one so it's weird :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright boys, I finally found the problem!

I bought my DNS with a mutualized hosting, then I bought my virtual private server. But I failed, at first, with my DNS because I did a redirect from the mutualized hosting to my server.

Probably this caused a third party cookies which failed with safari.

Anyway, I correctly added my DNS to my server and now it works perfectly.

I hope my answer will be useful to someone someday.

Comment: Your english isn't *that* bad. Besides, that's what the community at large is for :-)